# Add alternate charts to reputation tab

Tags: feature-request, reputation, profile-page

Right now, the reputations tab of a user's profile will only show a per-day bar chart (giving me reputation per day). I'd like to have the choice to see it represented as a cumulative chart (giving me reputation over time).

I don't know how much of a lift this would be, but charting libraries are a dime a dozen, so I hope it wouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Like a bigger version of the chart in the top left section of the profile?